# How to get the issuing certificate authority from an apple push notification certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, pki, amazon-acm

I want to import the Apple push notification certificate into AWS ACM. So first, I had to convert it to pem. Using `openssl pkcs12`, I was able to get the Certificate and the Private Key. But when importing it into ACM, I get this error : *"Provided certificate is not a valid self signed. Please provide either a valid self-signed certificate or certificate chain"*.

When I try to get the certificate authority, its empty. The p12 certificate was created from a cer file generated in developer.apple.com and using a csr file.

I tried downloading and using the apple certificate authority without success as I have this issuer : issuer=C = US, O = Apple Inc., OU = Apple Worldwide Developer Relations, CN = Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority.